# Why increasing refcount of zval not working?

Tags: php, php-internals

I'm dumping a zval container running on PHP version 7.3.5 (opcache is activated and PHP is thread safe enabled)  following this given code :

```
<?php 
$a = "new string";
$b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );
```

accordingly to php.net [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) Example #3 Increasing refcount of a zval it outputs **refcount=2** :

```
a: (refcount=2, is_ref=0)='new string'
```

On my setup (php7.3.5), it outputs **refcount=1** :

```
a:
(refcount=1, is_ref=0)string 'new string' (length=10)
```

I actually reach the same output with PHP5.6 as the php.net documentation.
What internally changed in PHP7 and why refcount remain 1 ?

Comment: The string is interned and as such doesn't use refcounting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in comments by Nikita, the string, as a constant literal, is interned - which is an internal term meaning something similar to "singleton for strings" - and so is not reference counted.

As well as interned strings, immutable arrays - which are arrays whose shape and location in memory may not be altered during runtime - are also not reference counted.

Xdebug 3.0 will be updated with [this](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/dd3c9b4127778dccbf61b98746797c7b88a4caf7) patch, which will allow it to show when a string is interned, or an array is immutable.